# Spin orbit coupling and effective gauge field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, gauge-theory, effective-field-theory

In the context of solid state system, the spin-orbit (SO) coupling from low-energy expansion of Dirac equation is

$$H_{SO} = \frac{1}{2 m^2 c^2} (\vec{s}\cdot (\nabla V \times \vec{p}))$$

My question: I saw people treat SO as a gauge field on the link of the lattice in effective field theory, which I'm very confused about. Could someone explains this?

There was a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409944) about why SO is needed to have finite berry curvature due to symmetry. The berry curvature $\Omega (k)$ can be thought of as an effective magnetic field. And maybe that's why they treated it as a gauge field in order to capture non-trivial berry curvature?